# How can I turn my projector off using command prompt or Powershell?

Tags: powershell, serial-port, projector

I have a Windows 8 computer hooked up to an ASK Proxima C520 projector using an RS232 serial.

I can not seem to get the projector to turn off through any commands that I have tried or have found online.

The ASK Proxmia manual says to use the following:

```
Method: Asynchronous communication
Bits Per second: 19200
Data bits: 8
Parity: none
Stop bits: 1
flow control: none
```

The command I'm wanting to use for powering off says the following:

```
Command: "A01" [CR] (Hex:0x41 0x30 0x31 0x0d)
Details: Power OFF immediately
Return: OK : [ACK][CR]   | NG : "?" [CR]
```

The commands I've been trying to work with are:

```
powershell
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
```

I just use this to verify that I am for sure using COM4.

```
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,19200,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("A01")
$port.ReadLine()
$port.close()
```

**What Happens:** The command prompt just sits there with a blinking underscore and does not allow any type of interaction after entering $port.ReadLine()

I have tried switching the WriteLine to: "A01 \r\n".

I had also tried using various versions of the following:

```
MODE COM4: 19200,N,8,1,p
COPY "A01" COM4
```

**My Problem:** I'm not sure why the projector is not turning off and is just hanging up in command prompt or just sitting there.

**My Question:** How can I turn my projector off using command prompt or powershell? I have to be missing something or confused about the serial commands work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN article listed below on the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort Class, the ReadLine method reads up to the NewLine value in the input buffer. However, the previous command, WriteLine, writes the value "A01" to the output buffer.  This ReadLine instruction is expecting some input value that you are never passing.  I believe you are sending the correct power off command but not sending a return command or confirming, as the projector is expecting. Definitely the ReadLine is not the right command.  I believe `r is the equivalent to the return key.

Try this:

```
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,19200,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("A01 `r");
$port.WriteLine("ACK `r");
$port.close()
```

It is possible that the RETURN commands are unnecessary...

```
$port = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM4,19200,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine("A01");
$port.WriteLine("ACK");
$port.close()
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.askproximausa.com/files/pdf/ASK-PROXIMA-C5-Series-Users-Manual-English.pdf